# .htaccess rules not working after setting haproxy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, haproxy

I am running ubuntu with apache2, I have a php system that is working with rewrite rules - all is working perfect.
Recently, due to increasing traffic I added a load balancer (haproxy), this is the second time I am using haproxy so I am not a pro.
When working with the haproxy I see the the .htaccess rules are not working - accessing the pages without the rules stil works.
This is the haproxy.cnf:

```
global
    maxconn 2048

defaults
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client 10000
        timeout server 10000


frontend www-http
        mode http
        bind LOADBALANCERIP:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
        default_backend www-backend

frontend www-https
        mode http
        bind LOADBALANCERIP:443 ssl crt /home/bee.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
        mode http
        cookie SRVNAME insert
        server node1 WEB1IP:80 cookie S1 check
```